# Reading userspace memory from kernel module

Tags: linux, memory, kernel-module

In a kernel module, I iterate through all the processes and read out the `vm_start` and `vm_end` addresses. The problem is that these addresses are in userspace and from a kernel module, I'd need to map them via `kmap`.

The issue I'm running into is that when using `follow_page` to get access to the userspace page, half the time it returns NULL, probably because there is a fault. Is there a better way of reading userspace memory or is there a way to resolve the fault and try reading again?

If a better approach exists, please mention it.